# I got problem with turtle fillcolor function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to draw a rose using python turtle. I got error in my fillcolor(). The turtle didn't colored the whole rose. I couldn't detect the problem. Can anyone help? Below is my code and the result image.

```
#This is a program drawing a rose using Python
#Author: Oyster
#Date Created: 19/6/2023
#Last Modified: 20/6/2023
import turtle

#Drawing the base of the rose 
def roseBase():
    turtle_rose = turtle.Turtle()
    turtle_rose.fillcolor("red")
    #Set up turtle style
    turtle_rose.pensize(5)
    turtle_rose.speed(10)
    #Set up the initial position of the turtle
    turtle_rose.penup ()
    turtle_rose.goto(40, 200)
    turtle_rose.pendown ()
    turtle_rose.left(40)
    turtle_rose.begin_fill()
    #draw the base of the rose
    turtle_rose.forward(40)
    turtle_rose.circle(20, 100)
    turtle_rose.circle(100, 80)
    turtle_rose.circle(25,130)
    turtle_rose.circle(130, 20)
    turtle_rose.circle(130, 20)
    turtle_rose.circle(15, 120)
    turtle_rose.circle(20, 20)
    turtle_rose.circle(90, 50)
    turtle_rose.penup()
    turtle_rose.goto(0, 60)
    turtle_rose.pendown()

    turtle_rose.right(125)
    turtle_rose.circle(180, 50)
    turtle_rose.penup()
    turtle_rose.goto(-70, 240)
    turtle_rose.pendown()
    turtle_rose.left(80)
    for i in range(3):
        turtle_rose.circle(50, 15)
    turtle_rose.circle(12, 60)
    turtle_rose.penup()
    turtle_rose.goto(-17, 120)
    turtle_rose.pendown()
    turtle_rose.right(80)
    turtle_rose.circle(183, -30)
    turtle_rose.penup()
    turtle_rose.goto(-80, 190)
    turtle_rose.pendown()
    turtle_rose.left(30)
    turtle_rose.circle(100, 100)
    turtle_rose.circle(50, 50)
    turtle_rose.circle(121,80)
    
    turtle_rose.penup()
    turtle_rose.goto(-60, 215)
    turtle_rose.pendown()
    turtle_rose.left(155)
    turtle_rose.forward(35)
    turtle_rose.penup()
    turtle_rose.goto(45, 228)
    turtle_rose.pendown()
    turtle_rose.forward(20)
    turtle_rose.penup()
    turtle_rose.goto(-40, 234)
    turtle_rose.pendown()
    turtle_rose.right(50)
    turtle_rose.circle(7, 80)
    turtle_rose.forward(17)
    turtle_rose.end_fill()
    turtle_rose.hideturtle()

#Drawing the leaf of the rose
def roseLeaf():
    turtle_leaf = turtle.Turtle()

#Drawing the body of the rose
def roseBody():
    turtle_body = turtle.Turtle()
    turtle_body.fillcolor("green")
    turtle_body.pensize(5)
    turtle_body.speed(10)
    turtle_body.penup()
    turtle_body.goto(-10, 55)
    turtle_body.pendown()
    turtle_body.right(90)
    turtle_body.begin_fill()
    turtle_body.circle(10, 180)
    turtle_body.end_fill()
    turtle_body.penup()
    turtle_body.goto(0, 40)
    turtle_body.pendown()
    turtle_body.right(180)
    turtle_body.circle(500, 50)
    

roseBase()
roseBody()
turtle.done()
```

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qApWB.png)

I tried to fully colored the rose but still got some white in there. I need some help to color the whole thing

Comment: This has to do with undefined behavior when you use self-intersecting polygon fills. Related: [Python 3.12 turtle empty inside of polygons that were filled in 3.11 with same code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77693070/python-3-12-turtle-empty-inside-of-polygons-that-were-filled-in-3-11-with-same-c/77694010#77694010). You'll want to use outline fills only, which will involve a bit of a strategic adjustment here. Note that self-intersecting fills *may* appear to work in certain environments, which might cause your code to look right on your machine but wrong elsewhere.