# Python 3.12 turtle empty inside of polygons that were filled in 3.11 with same code

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I was doing some work for my university using the turtle library in python and noticed that the code behaves differently on versions 3.12 and 3.11. On 3.11(and below) the stars look filled, but on 3.12 there is an empty pentagon inside. Is there any way to make the behavior the same on all versions? The code is below

```
from turtle import *
from random import *
from math import *

speed(10)
colormode(255.0)
hideturtle()


def make_star(step, angle):
    for x in range(5):
        fd(step)
        rt(angle)


for i in range(ceil(random()*50)):
    up()
    setpos(randint(-500, 500), randint(-300, 300))
    color(randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0,255))
    fillcolor(randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0,255))
    down()

    seth(randint(0, 359))

    begin_fill()
    make_star(ceil(random()*75)+5, 144)
    end_fill()


exitonclick()
```

I want to get fully painted stars. On version 3.11 and below this is the case, on version 3.12 this is not the case

P.S. here is an example of how the program looks like on 3.12(1 picture) and on 3.11(2 picture)

[image: Python 3.12 output has five-pointed stars with white space in the center -- which is to say, in any area which is not one of the triangles comprising the points]

[image: Python 3.11 output has five-pointed stars with the center filled]

Comment: AFAICT, you're depending on undocumented behavior. Code that does 10 moves instead of 3, tracing the _outline_ of the star, would arguably be a lot more predictable.

Comment: Nice example. Haven't used turtle so far. Just one small comment. Try to avoid doing `from xy import *`. This might cause problems if the library you import from changes (e.g. new names are added that colide with other names) and also IDEs might have problems with that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: you mean 10 instead of 5, right? 3 is a typo I guess, right? But that would mean, that the inner lines would not be drawn anymore. So in case you need them as well, you would probably have to draw an extra pentagon in the center.

Comment: it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0) pollute the namespace.

Comment: interestingly, python 3.12 is broken for `turtle`...

Comment: Changed, not broken. **"Whether or not overlap regions for self-intersecting polygons or multiple shapes are filled depends on the operating system graphics, type of overlap, and number of overlaps. For example, the Turtle star above may be either all yellow or have some white regions."** see https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/turtle.html#turtle.end_fill

Comment: Quite right, I did mean 10 instead of 5.

Answer (score 2):

The [docs for `end_fill()`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/turtle.html#turtle.end_fill) state:

> Whether or not overlap regions for self-intersecting polygons or multiple shapes are filled depends on the operating system graphics, type of overlap, and number of overlaps. For example, the Turtle star above may be either all yellow or have some white regions.

Your stars are made from polygons with self-intersecting regions. The solution is to draw the star outline rather than draw lines that run through the interior of the star shape. This guarantees OS-dependent behavior is out of the picture. There are multiple solutions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356543/turtle-graphics-draw-a-star), but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60030984/6243352) may be best (other than the wildcard imports it's using and lack of explanation). The thread also has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43316604/6243352) which explains the system-dependent behavior you're seeing.

On that side note, avoid wildcard imports. `from turtle import *` dumps over 120 functions into the global namespace, opening a huge potential for name clashes. Mistaking the instance and functional interfaces is another common error; if you only use `from turtle import Turtle` and create an instance, your code will be easier to understand and less error-prone.